# Secure - add username and password to the directory inside Manager App in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

Below /* secures only the main directory. The added Force login which should secure the 'test' directory
in the Manager App, but does not prompt the login window like on the main dashboard.
Anything other configurations need to add or changes ?

### Web.xml setting

```
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

```
    <!-- Force login  -->
 <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>test</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>test</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
            <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
            <realm-name>Editor Login</realm-name>
    </login-config>
```

### tomcat-users.xml setting

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="manager" password="1234" roles="manager-gui" />
  
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <user username="admin" password="1234" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui" />
  
  <role rolename="test" />
  <user username="test" password="1234" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui,test" />`
```

Tried to seure the directory on the Tomcat server. Need to review the setting in web.xml and tomcat-users.xml that can secure the directory /directories on Tomcat.